# Supply a default value to a mandatory Cmdlet parameter with a ValidateSet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, powershell, business-objects

Assuming a Cmdlet class:

```
[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet(System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon.Get, "LogonToken")]
public class GetLogonToken : System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet
{

    // constructor
    public GetLogonToken()
    {
      // set default auth.
      this.Authentication = "secWinAD";
    }

    // addtional properties omitted

    [System.Management.Automation.Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
    [ValidateSet("secEnterprise", "secLDAP", "secWinAD")]
    public string Authentication
    {
      get { return authentication; }
      set { authentication = value; }
    }

    // setting authentication here has no effect either
    private string authentication;

    // addtional code omitted

}
```

Calling the Cmdlet:

```
PS ..\bin\Debug> get-logontoken

cmdlet Get-LogonToken at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ServerName: SERVER
Authentication: <hit enter>
Username: USERNAME
Password: ********
Get-LogonToken : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Authentication'. The
argument "" does not belong to the set "secEnterprise,secLDAP,secWinAD"
specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set
and then try the command again.At line:1 char:1
+ get-logontoken
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-LogonToken], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,PsEnterprise.GetLogonToken
```

How do I assigned a default value to a mandatory parameter that uses a `ValidateSet`?

Comment: Please fix the typo in title: `manditory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

A mandatory parameter must have a value supplied. Hitting Enter at the prompt means you're giving an empty string or null; `ValidateSet` doesn't have anything to do with it. Even if there was no validation, a default value wouldn't be assigned by hitting Enter at that prompt.

You can make it optional, and then give it a default value, but if you don't supply it when you call the cmdlet, it will use the default and won't prompt.

Comment: I think making the parameter optional, then supplying a default value in the constructor is good option; it doesn't appear that tab completion will list the valid values for the `authentication` parameter.

Comment: @craig using `ValidateSet` should allow for tab completion; I'm not sure why that wouldn't be working.

Comment: tab completion didn't work the 32-bit or 64-bit version of either the shell or the ISE.

Comment: @craig I haven't written a cmdlet in C# before. Once you compile it (presumably to a DLL?) how do you get PowerShell to find it?

Comment: `PS> Import-Module path\to\PsCmdletAssembly.dll` is the easiest.  You can also reference the assembly in a PSD1 file: `RequiredAssemblies = @('PsCmdletAssembly')`.  Finally, you can add a class to the provide that derives from `System.ComponentModel.PsSnapIn`, then use `installutil.exe` (choose the one that corresponds to your project's targer framework) to register it.

Comment: @craig so if you use `ipmo assembly.dll`, you can run `gcm -mod MyModule` and see the cmdlets listed? If so, I can't understand why they wouldn't be tab completing, but again I have little experience with binary cmdlets. Might be good as a new question.